# Are you just repeating?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My suffix is united.
>
> My prefix is full.
>
> My infix is united.
>
> I am pretty full.

Hint:

> Wow! You look...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I look:

> gorgeous

My suffix:

> Us = you and me united

My prefix:

> Gorge = full of food

My infix:

> Org = an organisation is a group of people united in a purpose

I am:

> Gorgeous is another way of saying "beautiful", or pretty + full.

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> handsome?

My suffix is united.

> some --> sum (homophones)

My prefix is full.

> hand (as a collective noun), as in a hand of bananas or cards.

My infix is united.

> and

I am pretty full.

> handsome --> ample

Answer (score 4):

You might be

> Rococo

My suffix is united.

> Co, a prefix for indicating cooperation, unity, etc.

My prefix is full.

> ROC (republic of china) is quite populous.

My infix is united.

> Co again

I am pretty full.

> Rococo is an excessively ornamental art style.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> A tally?

My suffix is united.

> ally

My prefix is full.

> tall (not exactly full)

My infix is united.

> all

I am pretty full.

> a tally (as in an accounting record) can be pretty full

Are you just repeating?

> To tally is to keep score through repeated marks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> fulsome?

My suffix is united.

> some --> sum (homophones)

My prefix is full.

> ful--> full

My infix is united.

> U is a symbol for union in mathematics/set theory

I am pretty full.

> fulsome --> abundunt/copious

Answer (score 0):

Are you repeating because you are

> monotone?

My suffix is united.

> one

My prefix is full.

> mono --> more like single. Full because nothing else to be added?

My infix is united.

> a 'ton' of things

I am pretty full.

> Full of sameness?

Hint:

> Wow! You look...monotone (dull).